How to inflict self damage anywhere in Fallout 2?
How do I self-damage whenever I want?
Why? To make proper use of adrenaline rush perk as soon as I can get it.
I can’t find a single way to easily lower HP to 50% whenever I need it, making that perk almost useless.
Is there any consumable or weapon or something that could let me do that anywhere?

And beyond anywhere, if possible, I also want to use it:

in combat, to increase aim. My char have Strength 2. So +1 st improves aim for about 15 or 20%.
after combat, to increase carry weight. So i want to use it a lot, in places not safe to rest, to make it easier to loot 5+ corpses and trade with followers

PS: I play using fo2.exe app in android, so it is not that easy nor fast to control everything w/o all keyboard shortcuts and mouse with 5 buttons.

Any mods?
I imagined a possible coherent mod: use an inventory item "knife" on self causing 5hp dmg. I will see how dificult is to create it, but anyone feel free do implement and tell me please :), it could be used also to lower the effects of poisoning by 10-20%.

I would think you can probably find a couple of radscorpions somewhere, and just wait until they bring your health down to below 50%? I know it's not quite 'anywhere you want' ... I mean, there are enough things that want you dead in that game, that you shouldn't have much of an issue, if you just don't heal yourself?

@Time4Tea I just had to do that... run around new reno for a few days until a mobster encounter. Had to reaload like 50 times until i could defeat them, have no patty members killed, and remained with 25% of HP. The only good reason for so much effort was to gain access to myron science skill (Str2+1adrenaline+1jet+2buffout), so this is only useful and rewarding in rare cases.

I'll just add that I don't think it is the intention of 'adrenaline rush' for it to be active all the time. It is supposed to kick in to give you a temporary boost to help you through a tough combat. It's probably not one of the better traits in general though and I'm not sure the strategy to wander around at 40% HP just to get a +1 strength is a particularly good one ...

Roleplaying properly, it should only trigger when you feel fear, not requiring being damaged, and could put the player or npc in frenzy mode for a few rounds, and later cause distress debuff like jet. But... it is more a pc game than a table top rpg, so abusing its mechanics is expected to compensate the lack of more roleplayability. It is a good strategy if you have +20% critical chance, and dont care saving/loading in combat

Super Stimpaks?

a super stimpak heals 75 HP immediately, but the powerful nature of drugs used in the process will cause an adverse reaction from the organism, resulting in draining 9 HP after two minutes.

A.k.a "You can't heal above max HP so just take enough at once that the total damage of 9*[Paks] takes you below half HP".
And a Super Stimpak is 1 pound each.
From the other answer brings Dynamite and Plastic Explosives, which are more efficient if you can get Dynamite to deal at least 45 damage to you since they're 5 pounds each, and plastic explosives are always more weight-efficient than Super Stimpaks since they're 4 pounds each and deal 40 damage minimum.
But there's the stimpaks as a healing resource if needed, and depending how much HP you have, weight efficiency doesn't matter much.

It works outside combat and if you can rest for 10 minutes (or just wait real time 2mins i guess). Will work in many cases, I just need to find loads of it. It already helps, but i will add other moments i need to use it in the OP, thx, +1 ! Ugh... i cant vote yet..

@Daemons it is a good answer, already helps a lot, but it is not yet the best answer as it doesmt solve all my requests

There really aren't good options for this.
The cheapest option is to just find some weak rats or similar animals to attack you until you're at about 40% HP. There should be suitable enemies throughout the top-half of the map even in most cities; just don't kill the last one so you can repeat this. Vault City/Gecko and Navarro are the only exceptions I can think of in the top-half; the bottom of the map is significantly more dangerous and has more angry people with guns that are harder to work with reliably.
Natural healing has a minimal value of 1, so even with minimal endurance there's no way to permanently stay below 50%, hence trying to get to 40%.
No consumable items deliberately damage you. Super stimpaks will damage you as a side effect, but this will be extremely expensive, especially because they heal you. You can't go from 51% HP to 50%; the first stimpak fully heals you so you need to start over from 100% every time. Not really sustainable.
Explosives (dynamite/plastic explosives) can be used, but only outside of combat. Dynamite will do 30-50 damage, plastic explosives 40-80. These are expensive and the high damage ranges may make them unsuitable, but it is an option.
Grenades can be used, but only in combat. In theory you could activate combat anywhere; however you cannot target arbitrary hexes. You need a targetable critter nearby, and you need to not miss. Basic frag grenades will do 20-35 damage.

Yes, i thought in explosives too, and having 42hp may be too much indeed. I imagined a possible coherent mod: use an inventory item "knife" on self. I will see how dificult is to create it, but anyone feel free do implement and tell me please :), it could be used also to lower the effects of poisoning.

You can target (locked?) doors, usually without angering NPC's, which would make grenade-seppuku possible in most places.

You can improve your answer by adding the weights of all the different explosive items.

@Malady dynamite is 5, plastic expl is 4, grenades cant be triggered. I tested a dynamite on my own pants and it caused only 17 damage, could have been lucky tho.

@VeganEye Are you wearing any armor with explosive resistance? Boxing will also permanently raise some damage resistances (more without a fan patch due to a bug), although I can't remember offhand if that included explosive resistance or not. If you're in the vault suit you should otherwise have 0 explosive resistance.

As for grenades, no, they can't be armed like dynamic/plastic explosives. They're weapons, so you have to throw them at something next to you and take the blast damage. My answer just mentioned a weak critter like a rat, but throwing at a door is a better idea.

@VeganEye - Comments aren't supposed to be treated as permanent, so any info that's given in them and important should be added into the main thing (question / answer)

More a guess than a confident anwer, but when you leave companions behind they act more or less like normal interactive characters.
I wonder if it is possible to make them fight you back when you attack them, it probably also depends on the character whether he/she/it fights back or tries to flee.
If this works, then I wonder if it is possible to make them re-join your team after you fought against them (you probably have to leave the area and come back).
I cannot test this right now, but this could be an alternative to weak monsters.
If it works then you can fine-tune the equipment for the dealt damage (to them and to you) and for the available action points to control the situation.
Boxing gloves should be a good weapon to deal minimal damage.
You can massively overload a team character by selling (not exchanging) him cheap heavy items while he is not in your team. This reduces the maximum available action points (at least when the character is in your team). Afterwards you usually have to re-buy the items to get the character below the regular carry limit to do a normal item exchange again.
I don't know if this behavior was ever fixed, it works at least in the old version of the game.

If we can make it re-join the party w/o karma loss too, would be a good option w/o having to carry/spend weighty explosives or superstimpacks. In my specific case, i have 7 charisma, so i spend 1 mentats everytime i want the 5th npc back into the party, so it gets a bit more complicated to me. Also, would need to place all other followers far away so they wont help me against this one. Have not tested this yet.

@VeganEye I would tend to leave the entire remaining party on one map section and do the fight on another map section. If you need mentats every time then this approach will  indeed be very limited.
